# Does compiler optimizes unnecessary/redundant upcast away or Does it produce any IL at all?

Tags: c#, clr, il, intermediate-language, upcasting

From [Do redundant casts get optimized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278674/do-redundant-casts-get-optimized) I can see compiler doesn't optimizes unnecessary downcast (i.e. `castclass`) away. But now I am interested in a simpler case, " if compiler optimizes unnecessary upcast away?" This question only concerns reference type, not `boxing`.

It seems to my that `upcast` doesn't produce any IL, and hence redundant explicit `upcast` doesn't cost at all? Or because IL instruction is typeless, there is still performance cost for redundant explicit `upcast` behind the scene?

Or would upcast produce any IL instructions sometimes?

```
class Foo
{
}
class Bar : Foo
{
}
bool Test(object x)
{
    return x == null;
}
void Main()
{
    var x = new Bar();
    Console.Write(Test((Foo)x)); // redundant explicit to Foo, and then implicit to Object
    var y = new Bar();           // implicit to Object
    Console.Write(Test(y));
}

IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+Bar..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0006:  ldarg.0     
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0008:  call        UserQuery.Test
IL_000D:  call        System.Console.Write
IL_0012:  newobj      UserQuery+Bar..ctor
IL_0017:  stloc.1     // y
IL_0018:  ldarg.0     
IL_0019:  ldloc.1     // y
IL_001A:  call        UserQuery.Test
IL_001F:  call        System.Console.Write
```

Comment: its possible that the c#-compiler removes the cast to `Foo`, cause it is unnecessary

Comment: @Jehof Yep, that's what I am trying to ask: Does C# always optimize away unnecessary upcasting?

Comment: Sure, it is a very simple optimization to implement.  IL is *not* typeless, far from it.

Comment: I'm assuming you're not interested in the case where “upcast” is actually a boxing conversion, right? (E.g. `(object)1`.)

Comment: @svick correct, I am not interested in boxing.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is very much a micro-optimization. You should worry about making your code correct and readable. Only when you identify parts that don't perform well optimize those and measure whether your optimizations actually helped.

Second, even if the IL contained a `castclass` instruction, it could still be optimized away in the JITed assembly code, so it wouldn't have any effect on performance.

Third, I can't think of any case where an upcast would require `castclass` (or any other instruction). That's because in IL, methods are called directly by their metadata token, so there is no need to upcast to get the right overload of a method, or something like that. And IL doesn't have type inference, so you need to specify type parameters explicitly in any case, which means `castclass` is not needed here either.